# Typescript: Its return type 'unknown' is not a valid JSX element

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am creating a simple app which renders a list of courses and some details about the courses.

The course details are split into the Header, Content and Total.

In the Content section, is a child component: Part, however Typescript complains that the JSX element is "unknown" and I have no idea why it is.

Can anyone make sense of this?

App.js

```
    import Header from './components/Header'
import Content from './components/Content'
import Total from './components/Total'
import { CoursePart } from './types'

const App = () => {
  const courseName = "Half Stack application development";
  const courseParts: CoursePart[] = [
    {
      name: "Fundamentals",
      exerciseCount: 10,
      description: "This is the easy course part",
      type: "normal"
    },
    {
      name: "Advanced",
      exerciseCount: 7,
      description: "This is the hard course part",
      type: "normal"
    },
    {
      name: "Using props to pass data",
      exerciseCount: 7,
      groupProjectCount: 3,
      type: "groupProject"
    },
    {
      name: "Deeper type usage",
      exerciseCount: 14,
      exerciseSubmissionLink: "https://fake-exercise-submit.made-up-url.dev",
      type: "submission"
    }
  ]
  return (
    <div>
      <Header courseName={courseName} />
      <Content courseParts={courseParts} />
      <Total courseParts={courseParts} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Content component:

```
import { interfacePart } from '../types'
import Part from './Part'

const Content = ({ courseParts }: {courseParts: interfacePart }): unknown => {

  return (
 
    <div>
      <Part courseParts={courseParts} />
    </div>

  )
}

export default Content
```

Part component:

```
import { interfacePart } from '../types'

// eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
const Part = ({ courseParts }: {courseParts: interfacePart })  => {

  return (
  courseParts.forEach(part => {
  switch (part.name) {
    case "Fundamentals":
      return (
        <div>
          {part.name}
        </div>
      )
    
      case "Advanced":
      return (
        <div>
          {part.name}
        </div>
      )
       case "Using props to pass data":
        return (
          <div>
            {part.name}
          </div>
        )
  
           case "Deeper type usage":
            return (
              <div>
                {part.name}
              </div>
            )
            default:
              break
    
  }
})
  )
}

export default Part
```

types.tsx

```
export interface Title {
    courseName: string
}

export interface CoursePartBase {
  name: string;
  exerciseCount: number;
  type: string;
}

export interface CoursePartBaseDescription extends CoursePartBase {
  description?: string;
}

export interface CoursePartOne extends CoursePartBaseDescription {
  name: "Fundamentals";
}

export interface CoursePartTwo extends CoursePartBase {
  name: "Using props to pass data";
  groupProjectCount: number;
}

export interface CoursePartThree extends CoursePartBaseDescription {
  name: "Deeper type usage";
  description?: string;
  exerciseSubmissionLink: string;
}

export interface CoursePartFour extends CoursePartBaseDescription {
  name: "Advanced";

}

export interface CourseSpecialPart extends CoursePartBaseDescription {
  name: "Backend development";
  requirements: Array<string>;
}

export type CoursePart = CoursePartOne | CoursePartTwo | CoursePartThree | CoursePartFour | CourseSpecialPart;

export interface interfacePart {
  reduce(arg0: (carry: any, part: any) => any, arg1: number): import("react").ReactNode;
  forEach(arg0: (part: any) => JSX.Element | undefined): unknown;
  part?: CoursePart;
}
```

Comment: You declared your Content component as an unknown type constant.

Comment: It doesn't get rid of the error, Typescript still complains about Content being unknown

Comment: Could you provide us with the exact error message text?

Comment: (alias) const Part: ({ courseParts }: {
    courseParts: interfacePart;
}) => unknown
import Part
'Part' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'unknown' is not a valid JSX element.ts(2786)

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the content of Part component with Fragment, like this:

```
import { interfacePart } from '../types'

// eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
const Part = ({ courseParts }: {courseParts: interfacePart })  => {

  return (
  <>
  courseParts.forEach(part => {
  switch (part.name) {
    case "Fundamentals":
      return (
        <div>
          {part.name}
        </div>
      )
    
      case "Advanced":
      return (
        <div>
          {part.name}
        </div>
      )
       case "Using props to pass data":
        return (
          <div>
            {part.name}
          </div>
        )
  
           case "Deeper type usage":
            return (
              <div>
                {part.name}
              </div>
            )
            default:
              break
    
  }
})
  )
</>
}

export default Part
```

The reason for using Fragment here is

> A common pattern in React is for a component to return multiple
> elements. Fragments let you group a list of children without adding
> extra nodes to the DOM.

https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: Additional explanation, a React component can return only a single root element, and your Part component is returning many of them, therefore you have to wrap it in a fragment or a div, but fragment is a standard.

Comment: I tried doing this and it doesnt work... I get unexpected token

Answer (score 0):

The Content component is being typed to type of `unknown`. Type unknown is a type safe counter part of type any. However `unknown` type is much less permissive than `any` type.

To fix the error, change the type of your content component to the following:

```
const Content: React.FC<{courseParts: interfacePart }> = ({ courseParts }) => {
    return (
      // Your JSX code
    )
}
```

Secondly, edit your Parts component to return a React fragment when case is default and wrap your forEach with a React fragment so the block of code is interpreted as a JSX:

```
import React from 'react';
import { interfacePart } from '../types'

 const Part: React.FC<{courseParts: interfacePart }> = ({ courseParts })  => {

  return (
   <>
     {
      courseParts.forEach(part => {
       switch (part.name) {
         case "Fundamentals":
           return (
              <div>
                {part.name}
              </div>
            )
          case "Advanced":
           return (
              <div>
                {part.name}
              </div>
            )
          case "Using props to pass data":
           return (
               <div>
                 {part.name}
               </div>
           )
           case "Deeper type usage":
            return (
               <div>
                 {part.name}
               </div>
            )
            default:
              return (<></>)
         }
       })
     }
   </>
  )
}

export default Part
```

Lastly, update your `interfacePart` to return a JSX Element instead of unknown for the forEach loop.

```
export interface interfacePart {
    reduce(arg0: (carry: any, part: any) => any, arg1: number): import("react").ReactNode;
    forEach(arg0: (part: any) => JSX.Element | undefined): JSX.Element;
    part?: CoursePart;
}
```